# Trying to swap min and max values in an array java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Swap
{
public static void main(String args[])
     {        
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);        
     
     System.out.print("What is the size of your array? ");        
     int myArray = console.nextInt();                
     int[] size = new int[myArray];         
     int sum = 0;
     int max = 0;
     int min = 100;   
     int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size.length; i++) 
        {              
        System.out.print("Array index " + (i) + ": ");            
        size[i] = console.nextInt();            
        sum += size[i];
        
        
        if (size[i] > max) max = size [i];
        if (size[i] < min) min = size [i];  
        
        
        }

        System.out.println ("\nmaximum value is: " + max);
        System.out.println ("\nminimum value is: " + min);
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(size));
        
        temp = size[max];
        size[max] = size[min];
        size[min] = temp;

        
        System.out.println (Arrays.toString(size));

    }

}
```

I am having trouble swapping the min and max value in the array, I am able to find those values fine, and I even found a way to swap in with the temp variable, but I can't translate that into the array.

Comment: Your min and max values are being incorrectly used as though each was an index in your array.  You'll need to also store the value `i` for each.

Comment: You're saving just the value of the largest and smallest values. You also have to save the index of each so you can swap them. In `arr[i]`, `i` is the index of the element, not the value of the element.

Comment: If you don't have any (unknown to us) restrictions, there is another solution. You could sort all items and just replace the first and last elements. You could use ```Arrays.sort(size)``` to sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using max and min as array index to swap your values.That is not correct.Instead you've to keep min and max indexes,and use them to swap in the array.  I suggest you to complete your code like that:

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class Swap
 {
  public static void main(String args[])
 {        
 Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);        
 
 System.out.print("What is the size of your array? ");        
 int myArray = console.nextInt();                
 int[] size = new int[myArray];         
 int sum = 0;
 int max = 0;
 int min = 100; 
 int maxIndex=0;
 int minIndex=0;  
 int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size.length; i++) 
    {              
    System.out.print("Array index " + (i) + ": ");            
    size[i] = console.nextInt();            
    sum += size[i];
    
    
    if (size[i] > max){
       max = size [i];
       maxIndex=i;
     }
    if (size[i] < min) {
         min = size [i];
         minIndex=i;
       }  
    
    
    }

    System.out.println ("\nmaximum value is: " + max);
    System.out.println ("\nminimum value is: " + min);
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(size));
    
    temp = size[maxIndex];
    size[maxIndex] = size[minIndex];
    size[minIndex] = temp;

    
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(size));

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am pretty new, so I am sure that my code was all over the place.

Comment: Don;t mention.You can mark my answer as accepted,if it's working

Answer (score 0):

Only the part for max and min.

```
 int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 int iAtMax = -1;
 int iAtMin = -1;   
 for (int i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {              
     if (iAtMax == -1 || max < size[i]) {
         iAtMax = i;
         max = size[i];
     }
     if (min <= size[i]) {
         iAtMin = i;
         min = size[i];  
     }
 }
 if (iAtMax != -1) {
     int temp = size[iAtMax];
     size[iAtMax] = size[iAtMin];
     size[iAtMin] = temp;
 }
```

You could initialize `max` and `min` so that an update in the loop always updates. Then you have to use `<= max` resp. `>= min` to update the indices. (See `min` above) or you can check whether there already is a max and min.

If the array is empty (or size 1) you cannot (resp. need not) swap.